# Angular 6 add active class to ngFor element from another ngFor

Tags: angular, class, angular6, ngfor

I have two ngFor loop in html. one for showing header and one for body. Both are iterated on same array (Say A).
Array A is an element of each item of array B. example: B[id:1, arrayA: A[]].
Array B is iterated in separate ngFor loop which is parent for both A and B.

I want to add active class to both header and body of each element of Array A when any header is clicked.
This is working fine for 1st element of Array A. Both for all the remaining element this is not working on body.

Tried Codes - [class.active]="elementA.toggle" on both header and body and on header click - (click)="elementA.toggle = !elementA.toggle"

also tried with [ngClass]="elementA.toggle ? 'active' : ''"
Just working on header and not body.

I can share code if required.

In Component.ts :

```
categories: [category_A, category_B] // Array B
category_A: any =
{ id: 2, name: "A", toggle: false, subCategories: [subCategory_A, subCategory_B] }
category_B: any =
{ id: 2, name: "B", toggle: false, subCategories: [subCategory_A] }

subCategory_A: any =
    { id: 2, name: "SubA", items: this.items_Bread, subCategoryToggle: false } // Array A
subCategory_B: any =
    { id: 2, name: "SubB", items: this.items_Bread, subCategoryToggle: false } // Array A
```

My HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let Category of model.categories">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{Category.name}}" (click)="Category.toggle = !Category.toggle;">{{Category.name}}</a>

    <!-- Header Section-->
    <div>
            <div>
                    <a href="#subCategory.name" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let subCategory of Category.subCategories; let index = index" 
            [class.active]="subCategory.subCategoryToggle" (click)="subCategory.subCategoryToggle = !subCategory.subCategoryToggle">
                      {{subCategory.name}}
                    </a>

            </div>
         </div>
    <!-- Header Section-->

    <!-- Body Section-->
    <div  [attr.id]="subCategory.name" *ngFor="let subCategory of Category.subCategories; let index = index" 
        [ngClass]="subCategory.subCategoryToggle ? 'active' : ''" >
    <div>
    <!-- Body Section-->
<div>
```

this code is working fine for 1st element in categories i.e. category_A.
but for category_B  - Class active is not set in Body Section.

Comment: PLEASE SHARE UR CODE

Comment: I checked your code, and that works well for toggle `active`. What is your problem? You are trying bootstrap collapse as https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1Le9os0c/ This is html code for `debug`

Comment: @KingStone Thanks for sharing the bootstrap Collapse. I fixed it using "aria-controls" and "Id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let Category of model.categories">
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{Category.name}}" (click)="Category.toggle = !Category.toggle;" [attr.id]="Category.name">{{Category.name}}</a>

<!-- Header Section-->
<div>
        <div>
                <a href="#subCategory.name" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let subCategory of Category.subCategories; let index = index" 
        (click)="subCategory.subCategoryToggle = !subCategory.subCategoryToggle" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="subCategory.name">
                  {{subCategory.name}}
                </a>

        </div>
     </div>
<!-- Header Section-->

<!-- Body Section-->
<div  [attr.id]="subCategory.name" *ngFor="let subCategory of Category.subCategories; let index = index" 
    [ngClass]="subCategory.subCategoryToggle ? 'active' : ''" [attr.data-parent]="'#' + Category.name">
<div>
<!-- Body Section-->
```

MY Fix..